# JFrame в Jave то показывает, то не показывает элементы

Tags: java, jframe

Работаю в jave, IntelliJ.
Создаю Frame (Окно) в который помещаю разные объекты такие как: Panel, Label, Button и TextArea.  Проблема как раз в последнем (как я понял). Какого бы не было размеров мое окно (хоть setSize(1000 , 1000));, в свернутом режиме не показывает объекты начиная с TextArea и все что ниже. [image: Свернутый режим] Если его развернуть полностью (или просто изменить размер окна, потянув за угол), то все мои элементы магическим образом появляются[image: ![Развернутый режим]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxilv.png) В чем проблема не понимаю, да и гуглу такой размытый вопрос не задашь. Заранее все благодарю!

```
   PanelClass()
    {
       super("Name");
       // setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setSize(300 , 400);
       setVisible(true);

         setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
         JPanel Panel_with_img = new JPanel();
         add(Panel_with_img);
         Panel_with_img.add(new JLabel("img"));

         JPanel Panel_with_list = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
         add(Panel_with_list);
        Panel_with_list.add(new JLabel("Висельница"));
        Panel_with_list.add(new JLabel("Слово: "));
                JLabel Lable_slovo = new JLabel("_ _ _");
         Panel_with_list.add(Lable_slovo);
         Panel_with_list.add(new JLabel("Использованы: "));
         JPanel Panel_for_letter = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
         Panel_for_letter.add(new JLabel("Буква: "));
         JTextArea Label_Enter = new JTextArea("___");
         Panel_for_letter.add(Label_Enter);
         JButton Button_enter = new JButton("Ввод");
         Panel_for_letter.add(Button_enter);
         Panel_with_list.add(Panel_for_letter);
       }
```

Comment: Проблема однозначно в выборе менеджеров компоновки. FlowLayout например не уменьшает компоненты, а скрывает их за границей, если они не помещаются. GridLayout, тоже ведет себя по своему. Вам желательно описать поведение которое вы хотите и представить код, чтоб мы могли его посмотреть и выполнить, а затем откорректировать под Ваши нужды если проблема в нескольких строках.

Comment: делайте `setSize` и `setVisible` после создания и добавления всех компонентов, либо вызывайте `revalidate()`, для пересчета размеров и положения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод pack(), он автоматически подберет поавильный размер для Вашего окна, в главном элементе JFrame (вместо ручного setSize() ). Для того чтобы вручную распределить местоположение обьектов, используйте Layout’ы